# SQL: Add a result row from a distinct column value in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that look like the following (with more columns of course):

```
+------+--------+
| Name | DeptID |
+------+--------+
| John |     10 |
| John |     22 |
| John |     18 |
+------+--------+

+------+--------+
| Name |ClientID|
+------+--------+
| John |      5 |
| John |      5 |
| John |      5 |
+------+--------+
```

I am trying to get results out that look like:

```
+------+------+
| Name | Dept |
+------+------+
| John |    5 |
| John |   10 |
| John |   22 |
| John |   18 |
+------+------+
```

However, I cannot seem to puzzle out how to combine the ClientID and the DeptID together AND getting the additional row for the unique ID.

I tried using a CASE:

```
CASE
    WHEN t1.DepID <> t2.ClientId
    THEN t1.DepID
    ELSE t2.ClientId
END
```

But I ended up with 3 distinct ID's when I am trying to have 4.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Douglas!

You can use a UNION clause to solve your ploblem.

Try it:

```
SELECT name 
     , deptId
  FROM from dept
UNION
SELECT name
     , clientId
  FROM client
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM DEPT
UNION 
   SELECT * FROM client